# how to get co-ordinate from image and on image how to locate the source and destination point in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

How to get co-ordinate from image and on image how to locate the source and destination point in android ?

I use canvas for locate the co-ordinate.

[image]

Comment: Try to refrain from asking questions like "How do I do this"I. Instead, research the problem on your own first, try out a solution, and if that does not work, ask a question about what went wrong and how to fix what is at least a start of a solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Kasia Gogolek Next time i will remember this things.